# Как правильно прописать отправку сообщения клиенту с сервера?

Tags: java, websocket

С помощью `vert.x core 3.2.1` написал простенький сервер, который принимает сообщения от подключившегося пользователя, однако хотелось бы реализовать ответ сервера(возврат сообщений пользователя обратно).

**Сам код:**

```
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.buffer.Buffer;
import io.vertx.core.http.*;

public class serverTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        HttpServer server = Vertx.vertx().createHttpServer();
        server.websocketHandler(new Handler<ServerWebSocket>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ServerWebSocket webs) {
                System.out.println("Client connected");
                System.out.println("Client's message: ");
                webs.handler(new Handler<Buffer>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(Buffer event) {
                        System.out.println("Received data " + event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        server.listen(8080, "localhost", res -> {
            if (res.succeeded()) {
                System.out.println("Server is now listening!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Failed to bind!");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Через этот интерфейс и метод handle происходит прием сообщений:

```
@Override
public void handle(Buffer event) {
    System.out.println("Received data " + event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
}
```

Как я понимаю, нужно туда вкрутить отправщика и поставить какое-то условия, чтобы в случае если сообщение пришло, он высылал его в ответ. Однако я не совсем понимаю как это сделать=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поковырявшись и потыкав,обнаружил простой метод, благодаря которому можно слать ответы с сервера. Таким образом, метод handle перепишется следующим образом:

```
public void handle(Buffer event) {
System.out.println("Received data: " + event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
webs.writeFinalTextFrame("echo:"+event.toString("ISO-8859-1"));
```

Answer (score 3):

http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-core/java/ - смотреть доки

http://vertx.io/blog/some-rest-with-vert-x/ - классный пример

```
httpServer.requestHandler(request -> {
  //Тело
});
```

Comment: то есть добавить к вебсоккет-хендлеру request хендлер? пример может и хороший,но мне не нужно пока передвать html документы,просто короткие сообщения клиенту.

Comment: А разницы нет вместо html передавай любое содержимое строковое.

Comment: а если мне нужноо передать сообщение по вебсоккету? в данном случае хендлер использует интерфейс HttpServerRequest.можно это сделать так                 requestHandler(new Handler<ServerWebSocket>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ServerWebSocket req) {
                req.response().end("hello");
            }
        });
Но в таком случае он будет выводить ответ в браузер. а мне нужно веб-соккет клиенту.